# why google chrome popup page could not set localstorage value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Now I am using this code to set a localStorage value in Google Chrome Extension popup page:

```
methods: {
        saveConfig() {
            chrome.storage.local.set({
                "username": "d"
            },function(resp){
                chrome.tabs.create({
                    url: 'chrome://extensions/shortcuts'
                });
                Message("dd");
            });
}}
```

the shortcuts page could success open, but when I open the popup devtools and did not find the set key `username`, why did not work and what should I do to make it ok?

Answer (score 0):

you already set the storage successfully, but it only using third party plugin like `Storage Area Explorer` to show the value, this is the [download link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).